# border-spacing of table td between sections only

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I have a table with 3 sections:- Artwork, Barcode and Text Area whose Thead is as follows:-

```
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col" colSpan={7}>Artwork Area</th>
                <th scope="col" colSpan={8}>Barcode Area</th>
                <th scope="col" colSpan={8}>Plain Text Area</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr className='custom-tr'>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">X</th>
                <th scope="col">Y</th>
                <th scope="col">Rotate</th>
                <th scope="col">Scale</th>
                <th scope="col" className='same'>Flip</th>
                <th scope="col" className='same'>Flop</th>
                <th scope="col">Text</th>
                <th scope="col">X</th>
                <th scope="col">Y</th>
                <th scope="col">Rotate</th>
                <th scope="col">Scale</th>
                <th scope="col" className='same'>Flip</th>
                <th scope="col" className='same'>Flop</th>
                <th scope="col" className='same'>External</th>
                <th scope="col">Text</th>
                <th scope="col">Type</th>
                <th scope="col">X</th>
                <th scope="col">Y</th>
                <th scope="col">Rotate</th>
                <th scope="col">Scale</th>
                <th scope="col" className='same'>Flip</th>
                <th scope="col" className='same'>Flop</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

I want put a space between sections.i.e,only before first and after last td of cols set it constitutes. I tried using borders-spacing and margin property but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an empty `<th>` before first and after last `<th>`, and set `border: none` property and width range as you expect.

> `<th style="border: none; width: 100px;"></th>`.